# perl file manipulation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, perl, file, multidimensional-array

I have a file **File1** that contains these data :

```
NC_009066   5239    5308    trnA(tgc)   2.10899859667e-09   -
NC_009066   5309    5382    trnN(gtt)   7.03000463545e-10   -
NC_009066   5422    5487    trnC(gca)   7.09999799728e-08   -
NC_009066   5487    5557    trnY(gta)   3.72200156562e-11   -
NC_009066   5549    7097    cox1    291081744.81    +
NC_009066   7109    7180    trnS2(tga)  1.83000043035e-09   -
NC_009066   7183    7256    trnD(gtc)   2.5720000267e-09    +
```

and another fasta file **File2**

```
> NC_009066,1,0-17045,
GCTATCGTAGCTTAATTAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAACCCTAGAAA
```

I've put the file1 in an array line by line and then i can access each column by splitting each line on `/\s+/`.

```
for $line(@array){
    @column= split(/\s+/,$line);
    # print $column[5]."\n";

$gene=substr($seq,$column[1],$column[2]);#$seq extracted from File2....}
```

but I want to do is to take the second column from the 1st line with the 3rd column from the 2nd line `(substr($seq,5239,5382))` and then 2nd column from 2nd line and 3rd column from 3rd line `(substr($seq,5309,5487))`.....
what is the best way to do it ??

Comment: I thought about putting the needed data from @column in 1D array thus the new array will look like this (5239,5308,trna,-,5309,5382,trnN,-...)so i do substr on $new_array[$i],$new_array[$i+5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that the default effect of `split` is to split `$_` on whitespace, discarding leading and trailing empty fields. Most often this is what you want, and `split /\s+/` is unnecessary. If you want to invoke the default splitting on a variable other than `$_` you must pass a single literal space, *not* a regex, as the pattern argument, for instance `split ' ', $line`.

I suggest you start by using `map` to create an array of just the data in columns two and three.

Then you can loop over the data, extracting the start and end values and pulling the gene out of the sequence.

The code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;

my @data = map [ (split)[1,2] ], <$fh>;

my $seq = 'GCTATCGTAGCTTAATTAAAGCATAACACTGAAGATGTTAAGATGAACCCTAGAAA';

for my $i (1 .. $#data) {
  my ($start, $end) = ( $data[$i-1][0], $data[$i][1] );
  my $gene = substr($seq, $start, $end - $start);
  print "$gene\n";
}
```

Note that the loop is over indices `1` (the *second* element of the array) to `$#data` (the last element). This is because the body of the loop takes the first column of the *previous* element and the second column of the current element as a pair, and there is no element previous to the first.

Note also that you may have to adjust the parameters to `substr` as I don't know whether your indices start at zero or one, or whether they include the character at that index.

For instance with `$start = 1; $end = 2`, `substr('ATC', $start, $end - $start);` would return `T` when you actually mean `A` or `AT` or `TC`.

Comment: hi, i tried this method , i thought it's working but i realised that the first line of the file is not in the maped array @data

Comment: and that's the code i've written
open my $fbed, '<', $file or die $!;
  my @data = map [ (split)[1,2,3,5] ], <$fbed>;#i need 1st 2nd 3rd and 5th column

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What are you doing with the new data you're extracting? My code won't work if you start the loop at zero, as it takes the *start* index from the *preceding* record, and there's no record preceding the first. I suggest you update your question or, preferably, write a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You have figured out everything yourself already, you're just using `substr` incorrectly. The synopsis in [`perldoc -f substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr) says:

> substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH

but you are giving it two offsets. Instead, subtract one offset from the other to calculate the correct length parameter.

Comment: any method to avoid using 2 arrays, ?

Comment: @daxim: almost, but the question also requires the start and end offfsets to be taken from different records.

Answer (score 0):

Use a two-dimensional array:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@array); ++$i) {
    $$table[$i] = [ split(/\s+/,$array[$i]) ];
}

# you may put this into a loop
$start = $$table[0][1];
$end = $$table[1][2] - $$table[0][1];
$gene = substr($seq, $start, $end);
```

Also see [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).